# Partial keyword searching in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, search

Context:
I am trying to create a search function for my website where a user can type in full sentences and receive results back based on the matching of keywords in the sentence with words stored in a MySQL database:

```
**ID | Skill**
1    | Painting
2    | Carpenter
3    | Builder
```

For example a user may search *"I want some painting to be done"* and using the following MySQL query (along with a foreach and explode function) it will return **ID 1** from the database:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare ("SELECT username FROM users WHERE users.id IN (SELECT
skills.userid FROM skills WHERE skills.skill LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') GROUP BY 
skills.skill ORDER BY CASE WHEN skills.skill LIKE CONCAT(?,'%') THEN 0 WHEN
skills.skill LIKE CONCAT('% %',?,'% %') THEN 1 WHEN skills.skill LIKE CONCAT('%',?)
THEN 2 ELSE 3 END, skills.skill)");
```

Exam question:
The issue I have is that if a user was to type "I want a painter" then **ID 1** would not be returned. How can the query be modified to account for the fact that *painting* and *painter* are similar and so should be returned?

Comment: You would use a synonyms table to include synonyms for all the skills.

Comment: Exam question? Are you asking for us to do your homework?

Comment: @CarlMarkham PHP and MySQL for homework? What kind of educator teaches with those tools? Don't be silly.

Comment: @CarlMarkham It's a descriptor used in structured problem solving to say 'just what the hell is the problem' i.e. what is the exam question I'm being asked

Answer (score 0):

You can add to skills table a column called *synonymous* with some keywords for that skill.

For example, the "Painting" row will have a "paint painting paintor" in *synonumous* column.

Then you change your query to check for *synonymous* column insted of *skill* column.

This is the simples way, but requires that you put a synonymous to each *skills* table row.